# {{Peoples}} django template is not rendering my backend data in html page

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6Rxn.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btulH.jpg)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXn0b.png)

`in my views.py I have written function with dictionary in it u can see in image which is`

`in my html page I have written code of html and pass the variable of django with {{peoples}}`

`but it is not rendering in my live server   and I have attached all of my code images`

Comment: Please share the view, urls and template, [edit] the question. Share code, not images code.

Comment: You opened your template `myfirst.html` directly with your browser. You're not using django. If you want to render your template with the variables, you should first define url with urlpatterns from `urls.py` file. Typically add `path('', members)` to the `urlpatterns` list. Then [runserver](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/django-admin/#runserver) and access to the url provided by the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can't render the context param values which you have passed in your view through live server.

To render that value, run django development server in your local machine, go to main project directory in terminal

`python manage.py runserver`

Go to the respective url to see the context values rendered.